# How to delete an item in DynamoDB using Java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I know this sounds like a simple question, but for some reason I can't find a clear answer online or through StackOverflow.

I have a DynamoDB with a Table named "ABC". The primary key is "ID" as a String and one of the other attributes is "Name" as a String. How can I delete an item from this table using Java?

```
    AmazonDynamoDBClient dynamoDB;
    .
    .
    .
    DeleteItemRequest dir = new DeleteItemRequest();
    dir.withConditionExpression("ID = 214141").withTableName("ABC");
    DeleteItemResult deleteResult = dynamoDB.deleteItem(dir);
```

I have a validation exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: 1 validation error detected: Value null at 'key' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: RQ70OIGOQAJ9MRGSUA0UIJLRUNVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1160)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:748)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:467)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:302)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:3240)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.deleteItem(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:972)
    at DynamoDBUploader.deleteItems(DynamoDBUploader.java:168)
    at Main.main(Main.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

---

If I need to know the Hash Key in order to delete an item in a DynamoDB Table, I think I may need to redesign my database in order to delete items efficiently.

My table looks like this:
If that is the case, ahh... I think I need to re-design my database table.

```
ID | Name | Date | Value
-----------------------------------
1  | TransactionA | 2015-06-21 | 30
2  | TransactionB | 2015-06-21 | 40
3  | TransactionC | 2015-06-21 | 50
```

**Basically, I would like to easily delete all transactions with Date "2015-06-21". How can I do this simply and quickly without having to deal with the Hash Key ID?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AWS DynamoDB knows the column that is hash key of your table.
You just need to specify the value to be deleted. 
DeleteItemRequest has a fluent API for that :

```
Key keyToDelete = new Key().withHashKeyElement(new AttributeValue("214141"));
DeleteItemRequest dir = new DeleteItemRequest()
    .withTableName("ABC")
    .withKey(keyToDelete);
```

Comment: Question: do we need to know the Hash Key to delete an item in a DynamoDB Table?

Comment: Hi Sharon, I updated my original post at the very bottom. Could you guide me on that last part? Basically, I would like to easily delete all transactions with Date "2015-06-21". How can I do this simply and quickly without having to deal with the Hash Key ID?

Comment: DynamoDB only alows delete of one hash key and it has to be specified. It does have the concept of range key: it is an option that when specified you have a primary key that is the combination of hash+ range.  when you delete , you can specify a "range" of values in addition to the hash key (hash key still needs to be specified as unique) so if its possible, you can specify the date as the hash and ID as range.  however, this means you CANNOT fetch by ID only.

Comment: mind you, AWS also has SimpleDB that has greater query capabilities , at the expense of table size limitations.

Comment: Thanks sharon... so in my database scheme with ID, Name, Date, Value.... it seems I'll need to know the ID, Date in advance to delete each of the rows.  I hoped to be able to delete all 3 rows simply by knowing the date

Comment: Perhaps I should use "Date" as the Hash Key and an Attribute as a List of    Name ==> Value    pairs

Comment: seems so. DynamoDB is designed around a unique hash key, and all operations (fetch, put, delete) require one hash key value.

Comment: hash key must be one column of "simple" (not array) type

Comment: Thanks!!! That helps a lot. I think I should probably redesign my table and use Date as unique ID in this case ann attribute with a List of items that have maps

Comment: in this case just make sure that you have the date whenever you want to fetch/update/delete

Answer (score 0):

**For Kotlin:**

I have table with :
Partition key: `account_id` (String)
Sort key: `message_id` (String)

To delete an item fron DynamoDb I do the following:

```
    fun deleteMessageById(messageId: String, accountId: String){
        val item = HashMap<String, AttributeValue>()
        item["account_id"] = AttributeValue(accountId)
        item["message_id"] = AttributeValue(messageId)
        val deleteRequest = DeleteItemRequest().withTableName(tableName).withKey(item)
        dynamoConfiguration.amazonDynamoDB().deleteItem(deleteRequest)
    }
```